# AngularJS custom bootstrap CSS not working at component level

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-scope

I decided to convert a landing page to an AngularJS website, because I needed to add an admin section. To separate the website section from the admin section, I created two modules: `website` and `admin`.

The original website has been made with Bootstrap 3, and has a `style.css` that is custom CSS for all the Bootstrap and the website in general.

On the Angular version, I can load the website properly after I installed Bootstrap 3, and in the root-level `style.css` I do the following :

```
@import './app/website/assets/css/style.css';
```

The issue is that I don't want this CSS to be loaded for the full website (`website` + `admin`). With this configuration, the admin section is also affected by the CSS.

The import only works if it is in `style.css`. If I move the import to the website module in the root `component.css` styles won't load at all.

I know it must have something to do something with style scoping and `ng-deep`.

**EDIT:** The only way I can have the website load properly with the CSS imports within its own module is :

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now, there is no way to import css at the module level. Global styles are applied globally, and the default ViewEncapsulation makes it so that component specific styles don't bleed out to the rest of the app.

> If I move the import to the website module in the root component.css
>   styles won't load at all.

Importing that css at the modules root component only applies the styles to that one component. I also wouldnt look too hard at `ng-deep` as it is / will be deprecated https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Without knowing how many components are in WebsiteModule or what styles.css looks like, I'll present two options.

1) Rename styles.css (could get confusing since it's not going to be global anymore), import it in each of the components in WebsiteModule.

If that turns out to be too tedious (one bazillion components in WebsiteModule), then

2) I would take a good hard look at the styles.css in question, and see what styles should be applied globally.

Turning off ViewEncapsulation should be a last resort IMO.